# Local TCP port forwarding of HTTP requests based on the hostname header

Tags: http, reverse-proxy

I want to forward TCP from port 80 to another local port, based of the hostname in a HTTP request.

I want to avoid using a HTTP reverse proxy if its possible, since it will store the entire HTTP request before forwarding it - as I understand: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

If its not possible to avoid using a HTTP reverse proxy. Is it then possible to avoid storing the entire HTTP request before forwarding it.

Comment: You have _described_ the operation of a reverse proxy. What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: Then I want to avoid storing the entire HTTP request before it is forwarded. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the backend based on the `Host` header *and* not buffer the request body you'll need something like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or possibly [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) instead of nginx.